# Is אעדיף כל שמונה online in an accessible format?

Tags: chanuka, song-poetry

אעדיף כל שמונה is a set of piyutim by R' Elazar Hakalir for a weekday Shemoneh Esrei of Chanukah.  It was apparently said in Ashkenaz into the Middle Ages, but didn't make it into printed siddurim.

I can't find its text online anywhere except [this page](https://maagarim.hebrew-academy.org.il/Pages/PMain.aspx?mishibbur=600016&mm15=003181007040%2016&mismilla=3), which I find very hard to read.  Is there a more usable source?

Answer (score 1):

I found it on Otzar Hachochmah, in the book ממלכת כהנים by R' Moshe Chaim Leiter, starting on page 187 in the site's numbering, which is קצט of the book's numbering.

Following it are two other piyutim for Chanukah, also by R' Elazar Hakalir:

- איד נכון לצלעי is an expansion of וכניסי פלאיך, the Israeli version of על הנסים
- אנקת שיח שועי is a piyut for bentching

Comment: I won't accept this for the time being.  Hopefully someone can find one that's free.